# Is there mold or mildew growing in/on my Kalanchoe?

Tags: leaves, mold, kalanchoe, mildew

I picked up a Kalanchoe at the beginning of the summer without knowing anything about their care. I ended up over-watering it at first, which made it leggy and it grew many smaller leaves than it originally had.

But the mystery to me is a dusty covering on nearly all of the leaves that returns quickly when wiped off. At first I thought it was only dust, because I was behind on dusting my plants. But the dustiness returns much more quickly on the Kalanchoe than on a neighboring Christmas cactus.

Here are some photos of the leaves and the full plant:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is going on with this plant, and can it be saved? Or am I better off starting over next spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut it back to just stems an inch off the soil and it will regrow or you could move it along.  I can't tell whether it is a mildew or thrip.

If you are going to keep it I would isolate it and move to a sunnier location as the plant is stretched out from not enough light.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the low light making it leggy. It was in a lower light area at first, but I didn't consider that since I had moved it to a south facing window afterwards. Thanks for your advice. I ended up moving it along.